# What would be the appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask questions about Shopify?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Not [Shopify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopify) programming, more like system administration stuff.

Comment: [Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopify).

Comment: Thanks. Will you make that into an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: @AlLelopath Keep it. It's useful for later visitors.

Comment: If I do a [search on Shopify](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=shopify) in StackExchange, the recommended site does not appears. Almost all the results are StackOverflow and my question is not about programming, so StackOverflow is not appropriate.

Comment: Interesting...Web Apps also [has a tag for Shopify](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/shopify/info).  Have a look, if it's more useful to you I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've posted to your first suggestion, let's see how it goes. My comment was directed at philipxy who suggested some research when in fact I had done a search on "Shopify"

Comment: @AlLelopath Doing a search *in* SE sometimes doesn't work.  Try [this Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+Shopify&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS778US779&oq=site%3Astackexchange.com+Shopify&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.7396j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) search instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) is what you're looking for.  They have a [shopify tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopify) there.  There is no usage guidance for it yet, though, so check out [other questions tagged with it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopify) too.

**EDIT**

[WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) also has a [tag for Shopify](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopify), so your question might also be good for that website.

Comment: I would think [webmasters.se] is better. Mainly because the shopify tag on webapps is kinda dead, and it isn't well recieved.